# Lentitud al tomar fotografia con Expo Camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs, expo

Tengo problemas al tomar fotografias con Expo Camera. En ios anda super bien, en Android se demora mucho en tomar la fotografia. (5 segundos)

Probe pasandole como parametro `skipProcessing : true` pero sin resultado.

¿A que se debera esta diferencia de rendimiento?

Estoy ocupando EXPO V:56.0.0

```
  snap = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera.takePictureAsync().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
              imageuri: data.uri
            })
        })
      };
  };
```

Comment: ¿Has consultado la documentación de `Expo Camera` o has investigado en otras fuentes de información?

Comment: si, es un problema recurrente con la version que estoy ocupando... se me ocurren un par de trucos para hacer la experiencia de usuario mas amena... estoy viendo como

Comment: es información que te recomiendo agregar en la pregunta. Por ejemplo, si has visto algún tutorial o video, coloca el enlace de dicha información en tu pregunta.